# verifying iOS in app purchase receipt with C#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am verifying my ios `in app purchase` receipt  on my server using `C#` web service

I got receipt as string by doing below in Xcode:

```
- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSString* receiptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"%@",receiptString);

    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

    NSString *jsonObjectString = [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

}
```

and I am sending that string(receipt)  to my `C#` web service as parameter.
Here is my web service method:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Purchase Item Verify")]
public string PurchaseItem(string receiptData)
 {
    string returnmessage = "";

    try
    {
        var json = "{ 'receipt-data': '" + receiptData + "'}";

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = WebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        var sendresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string sendresponsetext = "";
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sendresponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sendresponsetext = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        returnmessage = sendresponsetext;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    return returnmessage;
}
```

It always return  `{"status":21002}`.
I have been searching for two days , but still can't find out the solution. Can someone help me, what am i wrong ?

**I am testing on sandbox that is why i use sandbox URL. I can verify the transaction receipt within my app.

Comment: Hi Jerry, dis you send jsonObjectString to web service? Actually i am also stuck to same issue.

Comment: Please solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188231/validating-receipt-with-the-app-store-in-net-is-success-but-when-sent-the-same

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got solution

The final code that works for me is:

```
 public string PurchaseItem(string receiptData)
{
    string returnmessage = "";
    try
    {
       // var json = "{ 'receipt-data': '" + receiptData + "'}";

        var json = new JObject(new JProperty("receipt-data", receiptData)).ToString();

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

      //  HttpWebRequest request;
        var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        //Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        //postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        //postStream.Close();

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }

      //  var sendresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var sendresponse = request.GetResponse();

        string sendresponsetext = "";
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sendresponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sendresponsetext = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        returnmessage = sendresponsetext;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    return returnmessage;
```

Spending two and half days just to change a method. Thanks GOD.

Comment: If it's any consolation, you probably just saved me two and a half days of work.  I'll add one more little addendum to the answer which will will help people managing subscriptions as well.  Also, can confirm the above code works fine in Xamarin, so you can do receipt validation on the phone if you use the Xamarin.iOS framework.

Comment: I was calling close instead of flush and getting a "Unable to connect to the remote server" after making a successful connection (and the inner exception was just telling me the host forcibly disconnected.) Hopefully anyone else searching for this issue will land here. Good luck (and thank you OP)

Comment: Worth noting that the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` constructor is now obsolete; [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests using `WebRequest.Create()` instead, and an `HttpWebRequest` object is returned if the URI scheme is `https://` or `http://`. This avoids an "Access to a static member of a type via a derived type" error.

Comment: I didn't use `JObject` and I had to change the formatting to use double quotes... `var json = $@"{{ ""receipt-data"": ""{receiptData}""}}";`

Comment: I am getting status code 0 and valid receipt data when validating receipt from iTunes  but when returned the same response via web service to app ,  status code is changed to 21002 and response i am getting in app is ("\"{\\\"status\\\":21002}\"")

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative asynchronous implementation using HTTPClient:

```
public static async Task<string> CheckReceiptWithAppStore()
    {
        string responseStr = null;

        string uri = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

        string receiptData = // Get your receipt from wherever you store it

        var json = new JObject(new JProperty("receipt-data", receiptData), 
            new JProperty("password", "paste-your-shared-secret-here")).ToString();

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {        

            if (receiptData != null)
            {
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

                try
                {
                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
                    responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error verifying receipt: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        return responseStr;
    }
```

The shared secret is not required for non-subscription based purchases.

Answer (score 3):

For managing subscriptions, @Jerry Naing's answer also requires the provision of your shared secret (can be retrieved/generated from iTunes Connect).  Easiest way to include this is just to add an additional property in the line defining the json var.

```
var json = new JObject(new JProperty("receipt-data", receiptData), new JProperty("password", "put_your_shared_secret_here")).ToString();
```

Failing to provide the shared secret will result in a 21004 status response.

Answer (score 2):

This code example was also helpful to me and may help others:  [For C# developers there is a useful open-source project called APNS-Sharp which includes receipt verification code that works in ASP.NET. In particular, the Receipt.cs and ReceiptVerification.cs files in the Jdsoft.Apple.AppStore directory](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp/blob/master/JdSoft.Apple.AppStore/ReceiptVerification.cs)

Found it from this page about Xamarin:  [inapp purcasing ios Transactions and Verification](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/in-app_purchasing/part_5_-_transactions_and_verification/)