# Apple Vailidating Receipt Exeption (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, post, receipt-validation

I'm having a problem with validating my sandbox receipt. The device sends the receipt to my Azure  App Service, which makes a POST request to the Apple Receipt Vaildation server. However, ~50% of the requests, I get an error back saying:

```
System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The other 50% does work correctly.

The C# code:

```
[HttpPost("{isSandbox}")]
        public bool Post(bool isSandbox, [FromBody] myReceipt myReceipt)
        {
            try
            {
                var json = new JObject(new JProperty("receipt-data", myReceipt.ReceiptString),
                           new JProperty("password", myReceipt.Password),
                           new JProperty("exclude-old-transactions", "true")).ToString();

                ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                var url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
                if(isSandbox)
                {
                    url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
                }
                var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }

                var sendresponse = request.GetResponse();

                string sendresponsetext = "";
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sendresponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    sendresponsetext = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }
                var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<responseBody>(sendresponsetext);
                if (responseObject.Latest_receipt_info[0].Expires_date == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                DateTime expireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(responseObject.Latest_receipt_info[0].Expires_date.Replace(" Etc/GMT", ""));
                if (expireDate >= DateTime.Now || responseObject.Latest_receipt_info[0].Is_trial_period == "true")
                {
                    // User has premium
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                telemetry.TrackEvent("Exeption: " + error);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I got this code for the most part from: [verifying iOS in app purchase receipt with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933133/verifying-ios-in-app-purchase-receipt-with-c-sharp)

The problem is that for me it isn't a 100% reliable. Any idea of why this is happening? Is this only happening for sandbox validation?

Comment: I have same error during today (in php requests). But 1 hours ago I receive a 404error at the Sandbox requests... Maybe apple server error.

Comment: This has been happening for me for months. I'm using Azure Functions for receipt validation and nowadays most of the times I will receive SSL errors.

Comment: @MuSoundiX have you found a solution to this yet? We are having the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, well... I made it like the following:

If my API gives this error, I return a different result. Then the App locally does the verifying. It seemed to me like the only solution. So I uploaded my App Build to the App Store. I have put in loggers into my API to see if this error also exists on the Apple Production server. At the moment, it hasn't. So at the moment, it DOES work a 100% on production, but it DOES NOT work for sandbox validation.

Comment: @MuSoundiX That's what I was assuming. But such an important service like In App Purchases where it ultimately comes down to the customer's, your and even Apple's money should not behave differently in the Sandbox. Since error acceptance is greatly reduced once the product is not free anymore.

Comment: @FlaGon You’re totally right. It makes the verification process way more complex then it should be... I hope Apple will solve this, although it looks like this has been going for months...